# Automatically apply clang-tidy refactoring to CLion project folder

Tags: c++, clion, automated-refactoring, clang-tidy

Is there a way to run and automatically refactor the entire CLion project source code by applying all the [clang-tidy](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/04/clion-2017-2-eap-clang-tidy/) quick-fixes?

Comment: What kind of project? VS? Cmake? What did you try to do so far?

Comment: CMake, I use CLion as IDE